# Suppose that $\liminf_{k \to \infty} \|\nabla f(x_k)\| = 0$

Tags: convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Suppose that
$$
\liminf_{k \to \infty} \|\nabla f(x_k)\| = 0
$$
and the sequence $\{x_k\}$ is bounded. Is it true that all accumulation points of $\{x_k\}$ are stationary points?

Can you find a subsequence $\{x_{k_m}\}$ such that $x_{k_m}$ converges to a stationary point?

Comment: I would like to understand this question. I think the definition of $\nabla$ should be given, and more context should be provided as to the context of this problem. Is this in $\mathbb{R}$? But maybe I am wrong and there is enough context, but I am unfamiliar with convex optimisation. Nevertheless my downvote will remain as you have not given your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $f \in C^1(\mathbb R^n)$.

Obviously, not all accumulation points are stationary solutions, since the liminf gives us only information about one subsequence of $\{\nabla f(x_k)\}$.

Counterexample: just consider the sequence $x_k = 0, x_{k+1}=1$ for $k \in \mathbb N$ even and $f(x)=x^2$.

To your second question:
This should be true if $f$ is continuously differentiable. Let $\{y_k\} \subset \mathbb R^n$ with $y_k \to y$ and
$$
 \lim_{k \to \infty} \vert \nabla f(y_k) \vert = 0.
$$
Since $\nabla f$ is continuous, we have
$$
 \vert \nabla f(y) \vert =  \lim_{k \to \infty} \vert \nabla f(y_k) \vert = 0.
$$
Therefore, $y$ is a stationary solution of $f$.